# Cannot delete a file. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

I have a file on my laptops SD card. I use the SD card as an extension of my hard drive.

When I try to delete this file (.jpg) I get the following error message

> Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

A quick Google search of this provides results for this error message during installation of Windows or on a Server.

I attempted the following command

```
del f "D:\GitHub\Site\Photoshop\restaurant-644504_1920.jpg"
```

But I get a similar image about it being corrupted.

I am able to write files to the SD card, amend files and delete files. This issue is occurring with only 1 file.

How can I remove this corrupted file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, **the filesystem is corrupted**. You have to fix it.

Right-click the card in *Computer*, select *Properties* → *Tools* → *Check*.

If you prefer command line, `chkdsk /f X:` will do the same thing (replace `X:` with the drive letter).  The `/f` switch means 'fix errors found`, as usually chkdsk will only report errors.

This may be an indication that the SD card will fail soon, make sure your backups are working and prepare a spare card.

Comment: Is this different to `chkdsk /f`?

Comment: It's either `chkdsk /f` or `chkdsk /r`, AFAIR it's `/f` by default but you can check a checkbox to make it `/r`.